# Which Beamer theme is this?

Tags: beamer

`Berlin`, the `Beamer` theme closely resembles this one, but not exactly like this. Can anybody please tell me what theme is this?

[image]

Comment: Everybody can customize and create new beamer themes so it is not necessarily a default one.

Comment: I recommend that you ask the author of the slides. http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~ghadafi/  You will see it in the list of publications.  It was for the Information Security Conference -- ISC 2012 (third from the bottom of his list of publications)

Comment: Specifically, how can I achieve such thin a title bar?

Comment: @R.Schumacher How do you know!!! Yes, I took it from Dr. Ghadafi's slides :)

Comment: Elementary, simply elementary.  I surfed with a couple of key phrases off of the slide and the full slide set was the second item with google.

Comment: @R.Schumacher: Some say, google is Dr. Moriarty in disguise ;-)

Comment: To get a title bar similar to the one on the screenshot you could use: `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}`